VB6 using app.path connection string appears in textbox
In my application I am using App.Path to connect to an access database, I have used this many times before without a problem only this time the connection string appears in a text box on my form.
I have a textbox1 that datasource is ADODC1 and the field is first name so when I run my application the first name in my database table "John" should show in texbox1 but what appears is "C:\Users\wien\Desktop\CRM" which I find really strange. Has anyone any idea why this is happening my code looks is as below.
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Adodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & App.Path & "\ESpringfield-CRM.mdb"
   Adodc1.RecordSource = "Clients"
   Adodc1.Refresh
End Sub

I tried changing field name, table names and database names but with out success.

Are you binding textbox1 through code or with the Designer?  If through code it would be useful to see how you are doing so.

OT: I suggest to NOT use App.Path as the location of the database, as in most environments regular users won't have write permissions to the folder the application resides in, e.g. "Program Files".
